# how to post hidden select box value

Tags: jquery

How to Post hidden check box vaule??
i have some select box in my page when user select one option  i have to make it hidden for not allowing him to re-choose other option ...

Is there any other option for doing this.. 
I have done it by asign that select box value to another hidden input box..

```
echo "<select name='".$i.$dateselect."'"."onchange='datecheckvalue()'"."id='".$i.$dateselect."' >";


 function datecheckvalue()
   {
   $('#3636').trigger('click');

   //$("#dateselect").prop('disabled', true);
   }
```

Comment: Your title says hidden select box and your question says hidden check box. Which one is it?

Comment: If you disable the form element it will not send the value in a form post. However, you can use "readonly" instead of disabled this way the item can not be edited and the form will still pass the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the readonly attribute instead of disabled such as:

```
$("#dateselect").prop('readonly', true);
```

readonly disallows the editing of a form element while still passing it in a form post unlike the disabled attribute.